# Swift : Error when the same button is reused. Error is "<UIButton: ; frame = ; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, swift2

(Swift 2 , XCode 7.0.1) I am reusing the buttons for a basic calculator app, and connecting(Control Dragging) all the buttons to same IBAction i.e

@IBAction func numbers(sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender)
    }

The app compiles successfully, but get the below error when clicked on each of these number buttons

Error is something like 
        *"UIButton: 0x7fba086146d0; frame = (9 459; 74 63); opaque = NO;    autoresize = RM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x7fba08614950"*

There should be something basic I am missing but unable to get any solution from similar StackOverflow threads. Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out

printing just the sender was the issue.

works fine now with this
print(sender.currentTitle)